# Differentiate between package and folders in eclipse decorators

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to write a basic icon decorator to decorate packages of my project.

```
package org.tdd.custom.decorators;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelDecorator;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;

public class CustomDecorator extends LabelProvider implements ILabelDecorator{

    @Override
    public org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image decorateImage(org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image image, Object element) {

        IResource objectResource = (IResource) element;

        //here I want to check weather objectResource
        //is a package, source folder or plain folder
    }


    @Override
    public String decorateText(String text, Object element) {
        ----
        ----
    }

}
```

Now, I want to apply icon decoration only on packages of Java Project, but I'm not able to differentiate between source folder and packages.

Answer (score 1):

You have a handle on the IResource, which is an Eclipse core entity.  You need to translate this into a JDT entity.  The proper API exists in the `JavaCore` class.  The method you are looking for is `create(IResource resource)`. It will return an instance of `IJavaElement` of the appropriate type.